# Has the scrollviewTexturedBackgroundColor changed in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, scrollview, textures

I am trying to make a table have a twitter-like background color. Please see: http://cocoacontrols.com/posts/how-to-build-the-twitter-ipad-user-experience

All they do is they use the scrollView Texture background and increase the alpha to 0.8 or so.  This darkens it from the default apple shade.  In my code, the following line of code works fine in iOS 4.3 and gives me a darker texture indeed. Moving to iOS 5, however, it's no longer darker, or for some reason it's not possible for me to darken the texture to be quite as dark.  Is this a known problem?

Thanks!

```
conversationTable.backgroundColor = 
  [[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the background color of the underlaying view (perhaps the window) to black. 
The default window background color is (now?) white and so your code will do exactly the opposite.

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```